# SQS async consumer, connection issues

Tags: amazon-sqs

In my app I have async SQS Consumer, here is a sample from the official documentation:

```
class MyListener implements MessageListener {
 
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message) {
        try {
            // Cast the received message as TextMessage and print the text to screen.
            System.out.println("Received: " + ((TextMessage) message).getText());
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the snippet of how I start my consumer:

```
        // Create the connection factory based on the config
        SQSConnectionFactory connFactory = new SQSConnectionFactory(new ProviderConfiguration(),
                AmazonSQSClientBuilder.defaultClient());
        try {
            // Create the connection
            SQSConnection sqsConn = connFactory.createConnection();

            // Create the session
            Session session = sqsConn.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(session.createQueue(pdfResponseQueueName));

            MyListener sqsMessageListener = new MyListener();
            consumer.setMessageListener(sqsMessageListener);

            sqsConn.start();
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            LOG.error("Can't start SQSMessageListener.", e);
        }
```

Recently, I have noticed that there are prolonged period of times when my consumer is sitting there without processing any messages (I see them piling up in the Queue on AWS dashboard), it seems that the connection gets disrupted and the consumer is just silently idles.

I was poking around a bit in the documentation and I noticed that the SQS is a wrapper around JMS. And, as such it has to implement the standard.

I looked at `Connection` interface: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Connection.html#setExceptionListener-javax.jms.ExceptionListener-

*If a JMS provider detects a serious problem with a connection, it informs the connection's ExceptionListener, if one has been registered. It does this by calling the listener's onException method, passing it a JMSException object describing the problem.*

However, when I look at
https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-sqs-java-messaging-lib/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazon/sqs/javamessaging/SQSConnection.java

that implements `Connection` interface, there is this sentence in java docs:

*Exception listener on connection is not supported.*

But the method looks like this:

```
    @Override
    public void setExceptionListener(ExceptionListener listener) throws JMSException {
        checkClosing();
        actionOnConnectionTaken = true;
        this.exceptionListener = listener;
    }
```

Doesn't throw `UnsupportedOperationException` or something of the sorts.

So, what't the correct way to detect a connection issue in SQS async listener and solve it?